# Handling large amounts of data retrieval on NodeJS server

Tags: node.js, server, google-cloud-datastore, gzip

A general question on how to lower latency of fetching and processing large amounts of iot time-series data from the database on my NodeJS back-end server. Sometimes I get timed-out even when I've set the time-out to be 15 seconds.

My current setup uses Google Datastore as my database for streaming data, NodeJS backend server for interacting with Datastore before passing the data to the front-end. I'm also using MongoDB hosted locally on the backend server as a caching layer.

The data-retrieval workflow for 1 request is roughly as follows: Device mac-addresses are queried from MySQL db and used to query cache for the requested time range, data from time gaps (not covered by cache) are then retrieved from Datastore, and aggregated into the requested time resolution, and additional parsing is done for some types of data if required.

Some strategies for improving performance I can think of include. Any other suggestions/ comments on the below strategies are welcome.

1. **Async** - Using async to fetch data from cache as well as Datastore (implemented)
2. **Streams** - Use fs to return data in streams to improve memory utilization
3. **Compression** - Use libraries like compression to reduce the size of data 
   sent over to front-end
4. **Clustering** - Use cluster to utilize multi-core processors (more for serving multiple requests and not so relevant for reducing latency for each request)
5. **Increase Server CPU/ RAM** - Provision for a more capable server (How do I know how much memory/ processor speed/ number of cores to provision for?)

Comment: In which location App Engine service located and where are you testing from? Also, this might depend on the network throughout in you region.

Comment: Currently I have not deployed the webserver to GCP yet. I'm looking for general strategies to make the data retrieval more performant, not that its always timing out on my requests, but wanted to see whether I'm generally on the right track, or if there are other things I can do to improve performance.

Comment: I've run same example as you provided, and on my machine, on localhost, this took 1.10s average for 3MB of generated array populated with 1.

Comment: Standard node.js streams will give you quite a headache - I'd suggest using a streaming framework like [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) - it will sort out easy data streaming transforms and multi-threading for you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to focus on reducing latency, however from my point of view you are using a too complex system involving technologies not efficiently used. You say your workflow is something like this:

MySQL ->  Cache(Using MongoDB) / Datastore -> NodeJS -> FrontEnd

First of all, see that you are using three different DB solutions. I know they are intended for different tasks, still it doesn't seem to be the most efficient way to go. I would say that the combination of Datastore+MongoDB doesn’t seem very natural either. Why don’t you use one of the following?:

1. A combination of Datastore + Redis (for caching functionalities). Here you have the official docs on how to [Cache Application Data Using Redis](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-redislabs-memcache). Here you have a more detailed tutorial on how to [Connect to Redis from Node.js on Google App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-redis-on-appengine) , doing all the interconection including  deploying [Redis on Google Cloud using Deploy Launcher](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/bitnami-launchpad/redis)
2. Use Mongodb directly.Here you have a tutorial on how to [Connect to MongoDB from Node.js on Google App Engine Flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-mongodb-on-appengine).

And whatever you choose the first or second option: Aren't you able to drop using MySQL?

If you use any of those solutions using [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/), you will have it easier to answer your questions related to Clustering &  Increase Server CPU/ RAM. You can try with [different configurations of your app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) to check the amount of cores and RAM that fits you best.

Nothing else comes to my mind related to async and compression strategies. As per Streams, you can use the suggestions by @Michał Czapracki about using [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet).

Answer (score 0):

In my app, I needed to give an option to join multiple mongodb collections (all data) and export into one CSV along with exported progress in percentage

```
exports.getExportData = (req, res) => {
    req.setTimeout(2400000);
    console.log('------------------------------------------ getExportData ----------------------------------------------')
    let url = urls.baseUrl + urls.endpoints.getData;
    url = postParamsToGet(url, req.query);
    let postContents = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        url: url,
        form: req.body,
        timeout: 2400000
    }, 
    receivedData = '', totalData = 0, column = false, lastEntry = 0, 
    successResponse = {
        status: {
            success: true,
            code: 200,
            message: 'processing...'
        },
        data: {
            url: [],
            processed: 0
        }
    }, 
    errorResponse = {
        status: {
            success: false,
            code: 400,
            message: 'something went wrong'
        },
        data: {
            url: ''
        }
    }, 
    exitChunk = false, filesRows = 0, fileCount = 0, pending = true;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(postContents))
    try {
        req.on("close", function() {
            console.log("close the connection!");
            errorResponse.status.message = 'connection broke'
            res.end(JSON.stringify(errorResponse));
            exitChunk = true
        });

        let fileName = `${md5((new Date()).getTime())}.csv`
        let email = 'abc@example.com'
        if (req.query.emailId) {
            fileName = md5((new Date()).getTime() + req.query.emailId) + '.csv';
            email = req.query.emailId
        }
        let tempFile = path.resolve('./modules/utils/temp/' + fileName);
        if (!fs.existsSync(path.resolve('./modules/utils/temp')))
            fs.mkdirSync(path.resolve('./modules/utils/temp'))

        if (!fs.existsSync(path.resolve(tempFile))) {
            fs.appendFileSync(tempFile, '');
        }
        const uploadChunkFile = (tf, fn) => {
            console.log('uploading to S3...', totalData, tf)
            return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                try {
                    if (!fs.existsSync(path.resolve(tf)))
                        return reject('unable to create file')
                    await exportCsv.uploadToS3(tf, fn, async function(err, status, url) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                            return resolve(fileName)
                        }
                        if (!status) {
                            console.log(status)
                            return resolve(fileName)
                        }
                        return resolve(url)
                    });
                }
                catch(err) {
                    console.log(err.message)
                    return reject(err.message)
                }
            })
        }

        // chunk process start from here
        request.post(postContents)
        .on('response', async function(response) {
            if (response.statusCode != 200) {
                errorResponse.status.message = response.statusMessage
                errorResponse.status.code = response.statusCode
                res.statusMessage = response.statusMessage
                console.log(errorResponse)
                return res.status(response.statusCode).send(errorResponse)
            }
        })
        .on('data', async function(d) {
            if (exitChunk) {
                res.removeAllListeners('data');
                return res.destroy();
            }

            let receive = d.toString()
            if (receive.indexOf("END_OF_STRING") > -1) {
                let receiveString = receivedData, pendingString = ''
                receivedData = ''
                receiveString += receive
                receiveString = pendingString + receiveString
                let splitedStringChunk = receiveString.split("END_OF_STRING")
                if (splitedStringChunk.length > 1) {
                    for (let str = 1; str < splitedStringChunk.length; str++) {
                        pendingString += splitedStringChunk[str]
                    }
                }
                let substrReceiveString = splitedStringChunk[0].split("START_OF_STRING")[1]
                let result = JSON.parse(substrReceiveString)
                let jsonData = []
                totalData = result.total
                lastEntry = result.o + result.l
                filesRows += result.l
                if (!column) {
                    column = Object.keys(result.data[0]);
                    jsonData.push(`"${column.join('","')}"\n`)
                }
                result.data.forEach(d => {
                    let joinRows = [];
                    column.forEach(c => {
                        if (d[c] !== undefined) {
                            joinRows.push(d[c].toString())
                        } else {
                            joinRows.push('-');
                        }
                    });
                    joinRows = joinRows.join('","')
                    jsonData.push(`"${joinRows.substring(0, joinRows.length)}"\n`)
                });

                await fs.appendFileSync(tempFile, jsonData.join(''));

                pending = true
                if (filesRows >= 1000000) {
                    filesRows = 0
                    try {
                        let uploadedUrl = await uploadChunkFile(tempFile, fileName)
                        successResponse.data.url.push(uploadedUrl)
                    }
                    catch(err) {
                        console.log(err.message)
                        console.log('chunk file upload error')
                    }
                    fileName = `${fileName.split('.')[0]}_${++fileCount}.csv`
                    tempFile = path.resolve('./modules/utils/temp/' + fileName);
                    if (!fs.existsSync(path.resolve(tempFile))) {
                        fs.appendFileSync(tempFile, '');
                    }
                    pending = false
                }

                console.log(`${result.processed}% completed${'.'.repeat(Math.round(result.processed/2))}, ${lastEntry}, ${result.o}, ${result.l}-- ${totalData}`)
                successResponse.data.processed = (parseInt(result.processed) == 100) ? '99': result.processed.toString()
                await res.write(JSON.stringify(successResponse))
                await res.flush()

                if (totalData > 0 && totalData == lastEntry) {
                    console.log('entered ....')
                    if (pending) {
                        try {
                            let uploadedUrl = await uploadChunkFile(tempFile, fileName)
                            successResponse.data.url.push(uploadedUrl)
                        }
                        catch(err) {
                            console.log(err.message)
                            console.log('chunk file upload error last time')
                        }
                    }
                    console.log('upload completed')
                    successResponse.data.processed = '100'
                    successResponse.status.message = 'url created successfully'
                    await res.write(JSON.stringify(successResponse))
                    await res.flush()
                    return await res.end()
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedData += d.toString()
            }
        })
        .on('end', async function() {
            if (totalData > 0 && totalData == lastEntry) {
               // response already sent
            }
            else {
                successResponse.data.processed = '-1'
                successResponse.status.message = 'no data found'
                await res.write(JSON.stringify(successResponse))
                await res.flush()
                return await res.end()
            }
        })
        .on('error', async function(err) {
            console.log('on error', err.Error)
            errorResponse.status.message = err
            return res.status(errorResponse.status.code).send(errorResponse)
        })
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('on try catch', err.message)
        errorResponse.status.message = err.message
        return res.status(errorResponse.status.code).send(errorResponse)
    }
}
```